# Empty string not display in bash

Tags: bash, quoting

Hi I write a scrpit in bash and I have a problem with the empty string
by exemple I have this array

```
array=('Hello' '' 'World')                                                                    
echo ${array[@]}
```

and my output is

> Hello (one space) World

and not

> Hello (two space) World

Someone know why ?

EDIT:

I found sorry I need to use "" when I echo

Comment: quote the array expansion - `echo "${array[@]}"`

Comment: or see details: `declare -p array`